# Please Help Me Troubleshoot Why My Site Is Loading So Slowly

Tags: performance, wordpress, optimization, yslow

My website is http://secretpassagesbooks.com/.  It runs on the latest version of wordpress and is hosted via GoDaddy on a shared web server.

My website takes at anywhere from ten seconds to one minute to load, and I don't understand why.  I have tested in IE, FireFox, and Chrome, and the page speed is the same.  I performed several speed tests at various online speed test sites and have an average load time of 5 - 6 seconds.  Yet when I click on a link to my URL or enter it directly it takes in excess of 30 seconds (sometimes more than a minute) to load the index page.

Here is what I have done so far to troubleshoot the issue:

- I have the YSlow and Page Speed extensions installed in Firebug
- Yslow test gives me a "Grade A -Overall performance score 90"
- My Page Speed a score is 94/100
- I have the W3Cache wordpress plugin installed and am using page, browser, and database object caching
- I've tried minimizing as much CSS and JavaScript as possible
- The site is using HTTP compression

Is there anything more I can do with this design, or is it  case of my shared web server being overloaded?  Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: What's your data layer look like?  Are you pulling data from an external server?  Do you have large queries?  The problem may not lye in the UI.

Comment: First red flag: GoDaddy hosting. Bottom of the barrel, but particularly popular for some reason. As others have said, hosting is most likely the issue, it's something you do have to invest more than a couple bucks a month in for proper performance with something like WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

YSlow, etc detect problems in the HTML, Javascript and CSS parts, and these are probably OK. It looks like your hosting is to blame.

Comment: Agreed, just looks like an abysmally slow server.

Answer (score 1):

If those plug-in results are correct (and I've no reason to doubt they are), then it's most likely a case of your virtual server simply being overloaded.

I presume you have no such issues running an identical site in a "local" production environment either, although you might want to try this to confirm if you've not already done this.

Incidentally, a tale-tell sign of an overloaded VPS/shared hosting solution is if the first page load is incredibly slow, but subsequent loads are "normal" - a common reason being that your "decicated" sandbox is being awoken from a sleep/low resource state. (This also seems to be the case as far as your site is concerned.) As such, it's possible (I don't know the details of this server, such as whether you have a "guaranteed" resource level for CPU, memory, etc.) that other sites on this particular server are using more than their fair share of bandwidth until your site kicks in.

Comment: Testing it locally is a good idea, but I think I already know what the result is going to be.

Comment: Sometimes you can fight back by having a `cron` script grab the front page every N minutes, thereby keeping your stuff from becoming completely swapped out. Of course this doesn't address the underlying problem (of oversubscribed resources) and may actually exacerbate it.

Comment: Yes, I tested everything on my apache localhost before uploading to my web server.  It looks like the concensus is crappy hosting.  I'm searching for the best rated wordpress hosts now.  Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 1):

Based on some tests from a tool that I built ([The Performance Grader](http://www.joomlaperformance.com/component/option,com_performance/Itemid,52/) at JoomlaPerformance.com), wow is it bad...

[image: Results Summary]

Notice that the HTML took approximately 21.83 seconds to download (from the initial request, to the last object being downloaded).  Not to mention that the page is nearly 300kb (which is fairly large for only having 7 images)...

[image: Request Information]

This is where the issue is.  Notice that the connection and DNS phases are fine, but the generation phase is really REALLY slow.  That's where your problems are.  It's server-side.  So, you need to debug why it's slow.  Some areas to look at are the SQL queries that are being executed (and if they are slow), any slow plugins, etc.  Try disabling things one at a time to see if each makes a measurable difference or not.

My "hunch" is that your database is either overloaded, or your queries are very expensive.  So in short, you can try another host to see if that helps (which is the solution more than you'd think)...

Comment: As per the comment towards the end of my answer (i.e.: the VPS has effectively been put in a sleep state), I suspect if you ran the same tool twice in the row, the second pass would be vastly, vastly different.

Comment: @midd: I ran it 4 times in a row, 21.6 second followed by a 18.0 second run, then 10 seconds then 6.8 seconds.  So it's slow all the time, but the differences could point to a overloaded server.  Though I wouldn't suspect "sleep" state (possibly swapped out of ram, but not "sleep")...

Comment: True. When I first hit it the response was ~30 seconds, but then seemed fully responsive. Must be one of those glorious "allow 'n' functioning VPSes at once, only have hardware resources for 'n-2'" style set ups. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As most of you pointed out, the issue seemed to be with the server.  I contacted GoDaddy and explained the situation.  It turns out that my site was hosted on one of their legacy servers and was most likely overloaded.  They switched me over to one of their grid servers (no cost) and now everything is loading quickly.  Thanks for all the responses.  I spent a lot of time tweaking the design, removing plugins one by one, reducing as many HTTP requests as possible, and generally went crazy trying figure out how to best optimize my site.  After a few days and a lot of tests, I could not accept that the problem was client-side, especially after all the optimization test I ran showed my site was ok. So good to have it settled...for now, at least.

Comment: @user587906 As a heads-up for how StackOverflow works, you probably want to delete your answer and add it as an update to your original question. (Then accept what you feel was the most helpful answer using the grey tick beside each answer.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy's webhosting is the bottleneck to your website, you should probably go for a VPS if you have got an advanced website with loads of lookups!